# Error handling Python socket - 'socket' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, sockets, server

I'm using a try/exception loop to catch socket errors for my server. 
Yet, I get this error "'socket' object has no attribute 'error'" for this code:

```
    try: 
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.socket.listen()
        return self.socket.accept()            

    except (self.socket.error, msg):
        print("Couldn't connect to the socket")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Does anyone know how to correctly catch the socket error?

Comment: Isn't socket.error is deprecated? [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.error)

Comment: You likely mean `socket.error` not `self.socket.error`. The error type is not a property of the socket object.

Comment: Yes! I realized that it has been depreciated